# Why was God's voice terrible to hear?

Tags: shemot-exodus, har-sinai

How fear-inspiring was God's voice on Sinai to the people who would rather have Moses speak to them than to God? Is there an explanation as to why they thought they would die if God spoke directly to them? Moses had protection and the people didn't? I believe there is a lot of discussion about that event, what do they say?

Comment: Please add Torah quotes.

Comment: I didn't understand. I put reference to the book that mentions this event, Shemot, Exodus

Comment: I see no need to recite the verse in question, every average Jew knows what I mean.

Comment: Is there an explanation as to why they thought they would die if God spoke directly to them? - where did you read this?

Comment: As Moses spoke, G-d answered him in thunder (Exodus 19:19). The Gemara (Berachos 45a) says: This verse requires further consideration, as there is no need for the verse to state: In a voice. The phrase, in a voice, adds nothing. Rather, to what purpose did the verse state: In a voice? In Moses’ voice, i.e., in a voice no louder than Moses’ voice. This verse instructs subsequent generations that Torah readers and translators should keep their voices at an equal volume just as Moses transmitted G-d’s word to the people and their voices were equal in volume.

Comment: Where did I read that they would die if God spoke to them?

and said to Moses, "Speak to us yourself and we will listen. But do not have God speak to us or we will die."

Exodus 20:19

What interests me is whether there are details recorded in Jewish sources about this event, that's all.